# Can I declare the same value for two attributes at once

Tags: javascript, html

For example, for accessibility reasons I want my `onfocus` and `onmouseover` to have identical values.  For the sake of maintainability I want to declare this once only.

What I'd *like* to be able to do is this:

```
<a onmouseover,onfocus="assist('hello');">linktext</a>
```

But, of course, that would be too easy, and doesn't work.  What's the best way I can achieve this [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)ing out of my tags?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The better way is to move all your event handlers out of the HTML and into javascript.

```
<a id="some_id">link text</a>
```

*(You don't need to use an ID, it's just for ease of demonstration.)*

```
var link = document.getElementById('some_id');
link.onmouseover = link.onfocus = function() {
    assist('hello');
};
```

If you wanted to take it to the next level, you could generalise it across many links. This example uses jQuery.

```
<a href="#hello" class="assist">link text</a>
<a href="#something" class="assist">another link</a>
```

Then you apply the event handler to all the links in one go (very dry!)

```
$('a.assist').bind('mouseover focus', function() {
    assist(this.href);   // you'd need to clean up the href here, but you get the picture
});
```

Comment: This looks very promising indeed. Thanks Nick.

Comment: In practice I'm using the `rel` attribute to pass my text along, rather than the `href`, but this is great, just what I needed.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Best I can think of is to use a function, set both events to call the function and put the common code in there.